# Can PCA be applied on One-Hot-Encoded data?

Tags: pca, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I'm completely new to the concept of PCA. From what I comprehend, PCA uses sum of squares method. With that said, I Came across a one-hot-encoded data (which means im dealing with categorical data).Can PCA be applied here? If yes, would it yield meaningless results? I'd be grateful for what ever response you provide.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

PCA can be used on One applied on one-Hot_Encoded data and it will give you output with no errors. But it has been designed for continuous variables. here is a detailed explanation of your Question  [PCA For categorical features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795141/pca-for-categorical-features)