# Dimensionality reduction methods for data including categorical variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining

My data set contains continuous variables(car price, Odometer), orderly variables(car age, sale year), and categorical variables(manufacturer, country, color). My target is to build a model to predict cars' sale prices in the second-hand market.

I encoded all categorical variables into dummy variables. Now my data set includes many 0-1 variables(100+), so I plan to reduce the dimensionalities to speed up. Now, my problem is which methods I should use?

My first choice is PCA. However, it is a method for continuous variables, so I should use it when my set contains many dummy variables.

My second choice is CATPCA. To be honest, I have no idea about this method but it seems can be used for my set but I don't know how to implement it in Python.

My third idea is to split my set and use different methods. For example, I split my set into two sets: the continuous variable set and the dummy variable set. use PCA on the continuous set and CATPCA on the dummy set. Then combinate two sets. But I have no theory to support this idea.

The final idea is to try all the above methods and choose the best one on the validation set. However, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795141/pca-for-categorical-features), even though the PCA method gets the best result, it is less meaningful. So, it seems the validation performance cannot be a good indicator for my question.

So, what is the dimensionality reduction method I should use on my dataset?

Comment: Don't split the datasets, it will affect the weights of the predictions. You can use an advanced technique called FAMD. <https://towardsdatascience.com/famd-how-to-generalize-pca-to-categorical-and-numerical-data-2ddbeb2b9210>

Answer (score 0):

*While you can use PCA on binary data or categorical data (e.g. one-hot encoded data) that does not mean it is a good thing, or it will work very well.

PCA is designed for continuous variables. It tries to minimize variance (=squared deviations). The concept of squared deviations breaks down when you have binary variables.

So yes, you can use PCA. And yes, you get an output. It even is a least-squared output: it's not as if PCA would segfault on such data. It works, but it is just much less meaningful than you'd want it to be; and supposedly less meaningful than e.g. frequent pattern mining.*